# Force submit when user selects a value for DropDownList unless the value is Custom

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am looking to force a submit once a user selects a value for DropDownList as long as it is not 'Custom'.  If it is 'Custom' I don't want the form submitted.  Instead I would like to have the startingDate and endingDate to show.  However, I don't want the startingDate or endingDate to show unless Custom was selected.  I am thinking this has to be done with jQuery or JavaScript.  Can anybody tell me how to achieve this?

Here is the code I have in the controller to pass the starting date, ending date and list for the drop down to the view:

```
List<SelectListItem> rangeList = new List<SelectListItem>();
rangeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Today", Value = "Today" });
rangeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Yesterday", Value = "Yesterday" });
rangeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Past 7 Days", Value = "Past 7 Days" });
rangeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Past 30 Days", Value = "Past 30 Days" });
rangeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Last Month", Value = "Last Month" });
rangeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Custom", Value = "Custom" });

ViewBag.rangeList = rangeList;
ViewBag.startingDate = startingDate;
ViewBag.endingDate = endingDate;
ViewBag.specifiedRange = specifiedRange;
```

**EDIT**

I modified my code to show an attempt at adding the script.  Below is the code I have in the view now.  It is not doing anything.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#range").change(function () 
    {
        if ($(this).val() == "Custom") 
        {
            $("p.down").toggle();
        }
        else 
        {
            $("form").submit();
        }
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        @Html.DropDownList("specifiedRange", new SelectList(
                    ViewBag.rangeList as System.Collections.IEnumerable, 
                    "Text", 
                    "Value", 
                    new { @Id = "range" }))
    </p>
    <p class = "down">
        Starting Date: @(Html.Telerik().DateTimePicker().Name("startingDate")) 
        Ending Date: @(Html.Telerik().DateTimePicker().Name("endingDate"))
        <input type="submit" value="GO" />
    </p>
}
```

Comment: It's really unfriendly to screenreader users to auto-submit forms like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it needs to be done with jquery.Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#idofyourdropdown").change(function(){
       if($(this).val() == "Custom")
       {
        $("p.down").toggle();
       }
        else{
       $("form").submit();
    }

    });
});
```

And class "down" to your `<p>` that you want to show.

Comment: I know nothing about jquery or javascript.  Where do I put the code you have?  Is it directly in the view?

Comment: You need to download a jquery library, reference it in your html and then put this inside script tag. Everything is here: jquery.com

Comment: But since you are on mvc3 everything should be already there. You just do <script type="Text/javascript"></script> and put the code I gave you inside this script.

Comment: I modified the question to show what I did.  It is not doing anything if I select a value for the drop down list.  when viewing the source from the browser I notice that the script is in the body of the page.  Is that a problem?\

Comment: I applied your update and still am getting nothing.  Does it matter that the script is placed inside the body of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$('#specifiedRange').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() !== 'Custom') $(this).closest('form').submit();
})
```